# Is there a way to easily communicate data from a python/flask app to a node.js app?

Tags: python, node.js

So here is the issue...I have had to use two separate SDK's for telnyx due to each offering a functioning service the other did not. One is in Python, one is in Node. Essentially I am sending a message from my phone to a telnyx API endpoint in python, and what I am hoping to do is communicate the number, and the message received in python over to my node.js app, which I will not have a problem formatting. I am just confused about how to communicate data between the two. Open to the smoothest suggestions. It is all server side, no client, just sending messages to a server and responding to them with another server based on the content of the messages.

Python/flask below:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/webhooks', methods=['POST'])

def webhooks():
   body = request.json

   messageSenderNumber = body['data']['payload']['from']['phone_number']
   messageSenderMessage = body['data']['payload']['text']
   newMessageSenderMessage = messageSenderMessage.lower()


   print(f"You have a new message from {messageSenderNumber}: {newMessageSenderMessage}")

   return '', 200

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(port=5000)
```

Here is the Node:

```
var telnyx = require('telnyx'). 
('KEY0178B7161E6B3873C151BDC3597EE42B_SHXIHH1anGGOgfhcIb3kjQ');

telnyx.messages.create(
  {
    'from': '+12182101811', // Your Telnyx number
    'to': '+18646662611',
    'text': 'Hello, World!'
  },
  function(err, response) {
  console.log(response);
  }
 );
```

My goal is to take the newMessageSenderMessage and messageSenderNumber variable's data and export it into my node app, that is all I need. Nothing crazy, just a phone number and a string from the python server side code, and same in node.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do the reverse, make a api call in the node, and from node make call to flask get the data

Answer (score 0):

Replace your return statement in the flask with this.
This should send back a JSON to your Node.js app

```
return {"newMessageSenderMessage": newMessageSenderMessage, "messageSenderNumber": messageSenderNumber}
```